# Front Brake Pads problem

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, oldsmobile, brake-pad

I replaced a front rotor and caliper on my 1994 Oldsmobile but not the pads, I have rust spots on it and even after I drive it the spots of rust are still there.

Does this mean that the pads are not touching the rotor, and new ones are needed?

My brakes do not stop as well as they should. What should I do?

I need to get a better brake pedal.

Comment: Yes, if the pads are touching, the surface rust will be gone. What should you do? Get new pads. Replacing the rotor but not the pads is not suggested.

Answer (score 1):

From [quora.com](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-ways-I-can-remove-rust-from-brake-rotors):

> Besides being an aesthetic thing, rust really isn't a problem on brake rotors. On the braking surface itself, the worst rust could do is slightly modify the friction coefficient for a period of time before it was worn down. You won't notice it. Though, with general use, your brake pads will rub off the rust. If it really bothers you, try some moderate duty braking, say, slowing down coming off the freeway onto a ramp.

Having a bit of rust on your rotors or pads shouldn't be an issue.  However, if you replaced your rotors and calipers, it's recommendable to replace pads at the same time.

Comment: Completely agree with replacing pads when you replace rotors.